# How do I transfer ERC20 tokens using Ether.js?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat, erc20

I'm trying to test my smart contract in Hardhat, but in order to do so I first need to send some ERC20 tokens to my contract (for this test I'm using USDC).

In my test I've impersonated a USDC whale, but how do I actually transfer the USDC to my contract?

```js
it("USDC test", async function () {
    const testContract =
        await ethers.getContractFactory("TestContract")
            .then(contract => contract.deploy());
    await testContract.deployed();

    // Impersonate USDC whale
    await network.provider.request({
        method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
        params: [USDC_WHALE_ADDRESS],
    });
    const usdcWhale = await ethers.provider.getSigner(USDC_WHALE_ADDRESS);

    // Need to transfer USDC from usdcWhale to testContract
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To transfer an ERC20 token you first need to deploy the token's main contract. You'll need the tokens contract address as well as the [ERC20 ABI](https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/).

```js
const USDC_ADDRESS = "0x6262998ced04146fa42253a5c0af90ca02dfd2a3";
const ERC20ABI = require('./ERC20ABI.json');

const provider = ethers.provider;
const USDC = new ethers.Contract(USDC_ADDRESS, ERC20ABI, provider);
```

Then to transfer 100 USDC from `usdcWhale` to `testContract` do:

```js
await USDC.connect(usdcWhale).transfer(testContract.address, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the latest version of ether.js is "6.7.1".
Maybe, it is a bit different between using latest version and older versions.

Now, I am going to recommend my codebase by using ether.js _v6.7.1.
I implemented the USDT Token Transfer by using ether.js in React Project.

```
import { ethers, Signer } from "ethers";

const usdtContractAddress = "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7";

const transferABI = [
  {
    name: "transfer",
    type: "function",
    inputs: [
      {
        name: "_to",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        type: "uint256",
        name: "_tokens",
      },
    ],
    constant: false,
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
  },
];

const signer: Signer = await provider.getSigner();
const token = new ethers.Contract(usdtContractAddress, transferABI, signer);
const amount = ethers.parseUnits(usdtAmount, 18);
await token
  .transfer("Recipient_Wallet_Address", amount)
  .then((transferResult: any) => {
    console.log("transferResult", transferResult);
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.error("Error", error);
});
```

I hope this will be helpful for you.

Best.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).